# Message of the day exited with return code 2

Tags: login, motd

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and Message of the day does not work anymore.
When I login no information is shown.

When I run

```
run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/
```

I get an error

```
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d//50-landscape-sysinfo exited with return code 2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I have experienced that, too. What fixed it for me is by reverting to an earlier version of Twisted. The issue started occurring on *Twisted* version `21.2.0`. I uninstalled that version by executing:

```
sudo pip uninstall twisted
```

Then, installed Twisted again, but this time using the version `20.3.0` by executing this:

```
sudo pip install twisted==20.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason!

On this computer is vmware vsphere-cli 6.7 installed.
It installs an own version of python six lib with a python cache file six.pyc.

This cache file produced an import error in /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo, which in turn exited with error 2.

All I had to do was, remove the cache files.

```
rm /usr/src/vmware-vsphere-cli-distrib/bin/six.pyc
rm /usr/bin/six.pyc
```

They were rebuilt after first run.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some more things.

```
apt remove python-twisted
apt remove python3-twisted
apt install python-pip
apt install python3-pip
pip install twisted==20.3.0
pip3 install twisted==20.3.0
```

That solved it for me.